# How to get Databricks time interval columns from JDBC driver methods

Tags: java, jdbc, databricks

My goal is to create a Java application that gets the schema (column names, types, comments) of Databricks tables. I am using Databricks JDBC driver version 2.6.33 (the latest one as of today).

I tried to use the JDBC driver to get the metadata from the connection with `connection.getMetaData()`, and use the standard method `getColumns(catalogName, schemaName, tableName, null)` to retrieve the schema of my tables.

Doing this, I get all the columns metadata except for one type of columns: [time interval](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/interval-type.html) columns. The ResultSet returned by the `getColumns` method simply does not contain rows for time interval columns: this is not a type mapping problem.

Is there a way to get metadata about time interval columns from the JDBC driver directly, or is it a limitation?

I could use a `DESCRIBE TABLE` statement for each table instead (the result set includes time interval columns), but I guess that would be less optimised, and I would like to add in the future other information like column size, nullable, reference columns... That are returned by `getColumns` but not by `DESCRIBE TABLE`.